# Dancer2 app with Postgresql on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, perl, heroku, dancer

I'm trying to deploy a small Dancer2 app which uses a Postgresql on Heroku.
So far I tried to approaches:
a) I typed the `heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql` the created by hand all the tables and granted permissions to the default owner witch I found in my heroku db connections settings. Then I added the following connections settings to my config.yml file:

```
DBIC:
     d1ofgde:
       dsn:  'dbi:Pg:dbname=d1ofgde'
       user: 'ygcexhxtprm'
       password: 'izU2xTVDfd5T5Byy4M4Xhk'
       host: 'ec2-54-244-50-186.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
       port: 5432
       options:
         RaiseError: 1
         PrintError: 1
       schema_class: 'My::Schema
```

This failed .

b) I tried to push my local postgres db on heroku with this command:

```
PGUSER=test PGPASSWORD=test heroku pg:push mytestdb DATABASE_URL postgres://ygcexmzlhxtprm:izU2xTVDfd5RekzT5Byy4M4Xhk@ec2-54-243-50-185.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d1ofgdng49tf0e --app  lit-mesa-10053
```

The push hand an error:

```
:pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
    Command was: COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language
```

But when i logged in  my heroku postgres i saw the tables inside it .

In both cases i used the same structure for my connections settings in my config.yml. And got the same error message:

```
2016-06-30T10:01:59.918775+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lit-mesa-10053.herokuapp.com request_id=99195ea6-fb7e-488c-93e8-2b7b5e306432 fwd="89.122.156.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-06-30T10:02:00.403773+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lit-mesa-10053.herokuapp.com request_id=dae4956e-954c-498b-8a32-e8ef8dc01c43 fwd="89.122.156.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-06-30T10:12:07.295999+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-06-30T10:12:14.677356+00:00 app[web.1]: Error while loading /app/app.psgi: The schema mytestdb is not configured at /app/local/lib/perl5/DBICx/Sugar.pm line 52, <DATA> line 1.
2016-06-30T10:12:14.677382+00:00 app[web.1]: Compilation failed in require at /app/app.psgi line 11, <DATA> line 1.
2016-06-30T10:12:15.886678+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255
2016-06-30T10:12:20.228220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lit-mesa-10053.herokuapp.com request_id=36a8291d-fce1-485e-979c-986db9cbf9b7 fwd="89.122.156.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 0):

So i fix my bug with this code : in myapp.pm 
i added this lines :

```
    my $env_url = $ENV{MYAPP_DB_DSN};
    my $env_user = $ENV{MYAPP_DB_USERNAME};
    my $env_password = $ENV{MYAPP_DB_PASSWORD};
my $schema = My::Schema->connect("$env_url;user=$env_user;password=$env_password");
```

then with `heroku config:set` i gave values to

```
MyAPP_DB_DSN='dbi:Pg:dbname=mydb; host=myherokuhost'; port=5432'
MYAPP_DB_USERNAME=myusername  
MYAPP_DB_PASSWORD=mypass
```

and it works now